# Finding eigenvalues of a complex symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: python, matrix, eigenvalues

I am trying to find specific eigenvalues and -vectors of a large complex symmetric tridiagonal matrix (at least 10000x10000, and ideally larger). I know roughly which eigenvalues I am looking for, so I've been using scipy.linalg.sparse.eigs (really ARPACK) to find them. Unfortunately, this has turned out to be slow for large matrices - solving a 7000x7000 matrix took approximately 30 minutes.

I feel that there must be some way of using the symmetry properties of the matrix I am dealing with - it's not just any sparse complex matrix. As a comparison, when I use hermitian matrices of the same size, linalg.sparse.eigsh allows me to reduce the solution time by approximately a factor of 2.

Are there any freely available eigensolvers out there which implement efficient algorithms for diagonalising the kinds of matrices I am dealing with? Do such algorithms even exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a banded cholesky-like algorithm to generate L*L.', although the stability is questionable because you cannot bound the pivot growth (unlike the LL' positive definite case, which is well behaved). So perhaps a shift-invert strategy (since you know which eigenvalues you want) might be able to give you an answer. In the event you have to slog through a cluster to find a particular eigenvector nearby your chosen shift, you can exploit the fact that distinct eigenvectors (vi,vj) of a complex-symmetric matrix are orthogonal under a quirky non-hermitian "inner product", vi.'*vj = 0. You can use that fact to setup an outer loop that deflates your arpack residual against converged but unwanted eigenvectors on every arnoldi step, via gram-schmidt. Note this part is dodgy too, because that "inner product" $<vi,vi>$ can be negative/zero, so your deflation/projection/normalization gram-schmidt coefficients can go haywire, too. Ultimately, complex symmetry is a nice storage-saving property but does not really impart the same robustness as real/hermitian symmetry.

So lots of caveats, but FWIW I have written working software based on this - wouldn't suggest it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

LAPACK seems to have several methods for this [case](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node48.html). You would have to wrap the fortran code with f2py however. Either way, the algorithms certainly exist, and the LAPACK documentation provides references to the relevant articles.

On a slightly different note, make sure you're using a new version of gfortran or (better yet) Intels fortran compiler ifort. It might save you 20% or more (on runtime).

Comment: Ah - sorry for not being clear. The matrices I'm working with are non-Hermitian, so the link you've given wouldn't apply. By complex symmetric I mean that M[i][j] = M[j][i], as opposed to the Hermitian M[i][j] = M[j][i]*